# JWT User authentication service for Istio

Tags: node.js, spring-boot, jwt, istio

The document corresponding to Istio End User Authentication states that

If jwksUri isn’t set, make sure the JWT issuer is of url format and url + /.well-known/openid-configuration can be opened in browser,

[End User Authentication Istio](https://istio.io/help/ops/security/end-user-auth/)

I want to build a JWT Server which serve this requirement for Istio, and can be used as a centralized Authentication Server(SSO) for my micro service based architecture.

Putting it simply, i want to create a centralized JWT issuer which i can use with Istio, kindly refer some resources that i can go through to achieve the same.

you can also refer the link below to have some understanding of my requirement, its same

[Central JWT authentication / authorization service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43947120/central-jwt-authentication-authorization-service)

I just want to know how to create JWT Issuer, which can work with Istio, by simply passing the **jwksUri** as described in the document for Istio End User Authentication
Example

```
jwksUri: "https://www.googleapis.com/service_accounts/v1/jwk/628645741881-noabiu23f5a8m8ovd8ucv698lj78vv0l@developer.gserviceaccount.com"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a centralized authentification server yourself is a long and error-prone process that you can avoid by using an open source solution, like Keycloak or IdentityServer.

An example of using KeyCloak with Istio can be found in the [RedHat Istio Tutorial](https://redhat-developer-demos.github.io/istio-tutorial/istio-tutorial/1.0.0/advanced/jwt.html).

You can also use an Authentification as a Service like Auth0, Okta, Azure B2C etc, and all of those are OpenId Connect Conformant ([list of conformant services](https://openid.net/developers/certified/))